# Who decided the names for the other two parts of the original A Memory of Light?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, etymology, a-memory-of-light

In the foreword to *The Gathering Storm*, Sanderson mentions that he was contacted to write the final three books for the Wheel of Time series, which were at the time still part of *A Memory of Light*.

Has anyone said anything about who decided on the titles "*The Gathering Storm*" and "*Towers of Midnight*"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### *The Gathering Storm*: [Harriet Rigney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harriet_McDougal), RJ's wife and WoT editor

### *Towers of Midnight*: [Brandon Sanderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandon_Sanderson), co-author of the last 3 Wot books

> As for that book... well, it’s time for it to have a title. We’ve been calling it Shifting Winds up until this point, but that was never intended to be the final title. After a long round of conversations with Tor and Harriet, we settled on TOWERS OF MIDNIGHT as the title. There are various reasons for this, which I’ll go into more once the book is out next year. I’m pleased, however, as this was the title I suggested. It’s actually appropriate in an interesting way. **Harriet was the one who came up with the name for the first of the three, and the second one gets the title I proposed**. And so, we will (as I’ve been saying for a while) use Mr. Jordan’s title for the final of the three, A MEMORY OF LIGHT.
>
> <sub>[Brandon Sanderson's blog, Storm Leaders, Book 13 Title, THE GATHERING STORM Prologue](https://brandonsanderson.com/storm-leaders-book-13-title-the-gathering-storm-prologue/)</sub>

It was Harriet who came up with TGS, and Brandon who came up with ToM, and the latter which was accepted by Tor fantasy and Harriet.

And of course the last book AMoL gets the name RJ wanted it to have.